# How to select unique records when duplicates exist

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, unique

I am trying to write a query that will show only the latest HEAR_DT for each APEL_ID

```
SELECT APEL_ID, HEAR_DT 
FROM HEARINGS
```

| APEL_ID | HEAR_DT |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 01-OCT-08 |
| 101 | 02-OCT-08 |
| 101 | 03-OCT-08 |
| 102 | 06-OCT-08 |
| 102 | 07-OCT-08 |
| 102 | 08-OCT-08 |
| 103 | 09-OCT-08 |
| 103 | 10-OCT-08 |
| 103 | 11-OCT-08 |
| 104 | 23-OCT-08 |
| 104 | 24-OCT-08 |
| 104 | 25-OCT-08 |
| 104 | 25-OCT-08 |

When I write the query as usual, I get the unique records to an extent, but the records where the HEAR_DT are identical are both showing up

The HEAR_DT is a "date" and not a "datetime" data type so I have no way of using the time
component to select the Max

Is there anything that can be done to this query (or a different query written), that can show only unique records. I will like to show any of the ones that are showing as duplicates. It does not matter which of them get picked. (something like "Top 1" or "Any")

```
SELECT APEL_ID, MAX(HEAR_DT) AS LATEST_HEAR_DT 
FROM HEARINGS 
GROUP BY APEL_ID
```

| APEL_ID | LATEST_HEAR_DT |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 03-OCT-08 |
| 102 | 08-OCT-08 |
| 103 | 11-OCT-08 |
| **104** | **25-OCT-08** |
| **104** | **25-OCT-08** |

Comment: This is not supposed to happen - assuming that you don't have anything odd going on, such as `APEL_ID` being set to `'104 '` with a space at the end (assuming it's a string, not a number).

Comment: The way you put it, it looks as if APEL_ID is different, not HEAR_DT. Because, MAX will select its maximum value, but - grouped by APEL_ID - it is that column that make the difference. What is its (APEL_ID's) datatype? Are you sure it is **really** 104?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have pure date datatype, because Oracle's date is actually a datetime.

Comment: @littlefoot, APEL_ID is NUMBER(10,0)
The goal is to select one of the duplicate records (the "104" row in this case) such that we will have just unique rows, including the 104 record and it's associated LATEST_HEAR_DT

Comment: Your query can only result in one row per apel_id. You cannot have 104 twice. What tool are you using to select and display the data?

Comment: Add `dump(APEL_ID, 16)` to the select list and see what is the difference in both 104. For string it will print you a code points in hex

Comment: This way you absolutely **have to** create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as you claim that things that are used for years are actually not working. On the way to minimal you'll definitely find the answer by yourself

Comment: The APEL_ID is not some sort of unique or autoincrementing field that prevents duplicates entry. Basically, to explain the meaning of the fields: APEL_ID stands for Appeal_ID and Hear_Dt is the hearing date. So the system is inserting Appeal_ID (which like I said is not intended to be unique) AND the hearing date. If there are more that one hearings for that particular Appeal, you will have the Appeal_ID and the one or many hearing date entries. Sometimes more than one on a given day

Comment: Please, minimal and reproducible. `group by` never returned duplicate values for columns, that are in this clause. From the very beginning of its existence. The purpose of this clause is a grouping on the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. This works

```
SELECT UNIQUE APEL_ID, MAX(TO_DATE(HEAR_DT, 'DD-MON-YY')) AS LATEST_HEAR_DT 
FROM mytable  
GROUP BY APEL_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT APEL_ID, MAX(HEAR_DT) AS LATEST_HEAR_DT 
FROM HEARINGS 
GROUP BY APEL_ID;
```

should return exactly one row per `APEL_ID`.  It would not return multiple rows.

If you want rows from the original data, one row per `APEL_ID`, use window functions:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM (SELECT h.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY APEL_ID ORDER BY HEAR_DT DESC) as seqnum
      FROM HEARINGS h
     ) h
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```